# How do you get an <imc src=""> tag to not use a CSS style?

Tags: html, css

I have a web site that I am trying to add content to. My problem is whenever I add an image, it will not let me center it. In the style.css file there is the following style:

```
#wrapper img {
float: left;
text-align: justify;
}
```

This style is used to push the separate pieces of the nav bar to the left so it appears as a single unit. The problem is whenever I add an image to the page, it invokes this style, preventing me from centering it. Is there anyway I can circumvent this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add another CSS line to undo the floating. If you are trying to center the element, depending on the elements around it, `margin: auto;` should do it.

**HTML**:

```
<img src="" id="imgImage" />
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper img {
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
} 
#imgImage {
    float: none !important;
    /* margin: auto; */
}
```

Comment: You're going to need more specificity on the `#imgImage` rule (such as `#wrapper #imgImage { ... }`) or an `!important` to override `#wrapper img`.

Comment: i've added <div align="center"><img src="" id="imgImage" width="208" height="267"></div> and for some reason the #wrapper img is still take precedence

Comment: I added an `!important` to the float line, as per @muistooshort's suggestion.

Comment: @Chris: That's because `#wrapper img` has a higher specificity than `#imgImage` (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), adding the `!important` as in Justin's recent edit should sort it out.